# Deleting duplicates in data based on the conditions of a date column and a different column in r

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, delete-row

In my data, I have 10 unique sample dates for each of the 15 animals we measured clinical signs for. For each date, two people took clinical signs (temperature, swelling, etc) for each animal. Taking all other parts of the data into account, each animal has four rows with the same sample date. For two of the rows, there is one initial and for the other two rows there is either a different initial OR an NA (for when that sampler was absent that day). My goal in my data is to delete the rows which, for the same date, have one set of initials in 2 of the 4 rows (per unique animal), but an NA in the other 2 rows with that same date (for that same animal).

Clarification: There are other NAs in the Initials column that I would like to leave in. For example, for animal 6, I would like to leave in all of the NAs. But for the other animals with 4 rows that have two of those rows populated with initials and the other two rows have NAs, I would like to delete the NA rows. Thank you!

Here is some sample code:

```
Data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 24))
colnames(Data) <- c('AnimalID', 'DateSampled', 'Initials')

Data$AnimalID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6)

Data$DateSampled <- as.Date(c("2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-27", "2021-10-27", "2021-10-27", "2021-10-27", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-24", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-01", "2021-12-05", "2021-12-05"))

Data$Initials <- c("AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "AB", "AB", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Desired Output:

```
AnimalID  |  DateSampled  | Initials
1         |  "2021-10-13" |  AB
1         |  "2021-10-13" |  AB
2         |  "2021-10-27" |  AB
2         |  "2021-10-27" |  AB
2         |  "2021-10-27" |  CD
2         |  "2021-10-27" |  CD
3         |  "2021-11-10" |  AB
3         |  "2021-11-10" |  AB
4         |  "2021-11-24" |  AB
4         |  "2021-11-24" |  AB
4         |  "2021-11-24" |  CD
4         |  "2021-11-24" |  CD
5         |  "2021-12-01" |  AB
5         |  "2021-12-01" |  AB
6         |  "2021-12-05" |  NA
6         |  "2021-12-05" |  NA
```

Whether its for loops or a conditional vector, if there is an "AB" (or any other set of initials) AND an "NA" for the same animal id and sample date, I would love to delete the rows that have NA in them. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this using `dplyr`. `filter(!is.na(Initials))` wil remove all the rows with NA. `distinct()` will get rid of the duplicated rows:

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Initials)) %>% 
  distinct()

  EweID DateSampled Initials
1     1  2021-10-13       AB
2     2  2021-10-27       AB
3     2  2021-10-27       CD
4     3  2021-11-10       AB
5     4  2021-11-24       AB
6     4  2021-11-24       CD
7     5  2021-12-01       AB
```

#### Update

---

Thanks for clarifying your output, here is a way to achieve. First is to create a intermediate data frame for each animal and counting the number of `NA` per group:

```
Number_of_NA = Data %>%
  group_by(AnimalID)%>%
  summarise(n = sum(is.na(Initials)))

> Number_of_NA
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  AnimalID     n
     <dbl> <int>
1        1     2
2        2     0
3        3     2
4        4     0
5        5     2
6        6     4
7        7     4
```

If I understand correctly the group you want to keep with `NA` will always have 4 values with NA. You can use this to filter all the `NA` in the data frame as previously and then join the group with only the 4 NAs:

```
Data %>% filter(!is.na(Initials)) %>%
  full_join(filter(Data, AnimalID %in% Number_of_NA$AnimalID[Number_of_NA$n == 4]))

   AnimalID DateSampled Initials
1         1  2021-10-13       AB
2         1  2021-10-13       AB
3         2  2021-10-27       AB
4         2  2021-10-27       AB
5         2  2021-10-27       CD
6         2  2021-10-27       CD
7         3  2021-11-10       AB
8         3  2021-11-10       AB
9         4  2021-11-24       AB
10        4  2021-11-24       AB
11        4  2021-11-24       CD
12        4  2021-11-24       CD
13        5  2021-12-01       AB
14        5  2021-12-01       AB
15        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
16        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
17        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
18        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
19        7  2021-12-15     <NA>
20        7  2021-12-15     <NA>
21        7  2021-12-15     <NA>
22        7  2021-12-15     <NA>
```

#### Data

---

```
Data = structure(list(AnimalID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7), DateSampled = structure(c(18913, 
18913, 18913, 18913, 18927, 18927, 18927, 18927, 18941, 18941, 
18941, 18941, 18955, 18955, 18955, 18955, 18962, 18962, 18962, 
18962, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18976, 18976, 18976, 18976
), class = "Date"), Initials = c("AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", 
"CD", "CD", "AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "AB", 
"AB", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Update 2

---

Here are the modification to match your filtering. In the first data frame we `group_by()` animal ID and date, then calculate the number of NA (`with_NA`) and the number total of observation `total_n`. In that case if `with_NA` is equal to `total_n`, that means only NA are available for this ID and Date therefore these NA will be kept.

```
library(dplyr)

df_filt = Data %>%
  group_by(AnimalID, DateSampled)%>%
  summarise(with_NA = sum(is.na(Initials)), total_n = n(), 
            to_filter = with_NA == total_n) %>% 
  filter(to_filter == TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   AnimalID [3]
  AnimalID DateSampled with_NA total_n to_filter
     <dbl> <date>        <int>   <int> <lgl>    
1        3 2021-11-11        1       1 TRUE     
2        6 2021-12-05        4       4 TRUE     
3        7 2021-12-16        2       2 TRUE
```

Then we can use something similar to last time to filter all NA in the dataframe and then join with the one we want to kept based on the dataframe above:

```
Data %>% filter(!is.na(Initials)) %>%
  full_join(filter(Data, AnimalID %in% df_filt$AnimalID & DateSampled %in% df_filt$DateSampled))%>%
  arrange(AnimalID)

   AnimalID DateSampled Initials
1         1  2021-10-13       AB
2         1  2021-10-13       AB
3         2  2021-10-27       AB
4         2  2021-10-27       AB
5         2  2021-10-27       CD
6         2  2021-10-27       CD
7         3  2021-11-10       AB
8         3  2021-11-10       AB
9         3  2021-11-11     <NA>
10        4  2021-11-24       AB
11        4  2021-11-24       AB
12        4  2021-11-24       CD
13        4  2021-11-24       CD
14        5  2021-12-01       AB
15        5  2021-12-01       AB
16        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
17        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
18        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
19        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
20        7  2021-12-15       CB
21        7  2021-12-16     <NA>
22        7  2021-12-16     <NA>
```

In this case all the NA that have a matching Date and AnimalID with Initial will be discarded and only the NA without real Initial for this date will be kept.

> Note that I modified slightly the Data here to reflect on the desired output

#### Data 2

---

```
> Data
   AnimalID DateSampled Initials
1         1  2021-10-13       AB
2         1  2021-10-13       AB
3         1  2021-10-13     <NA>
4         1  2021-10-13     <NA>
5         2  2021-10-27       AB
6         2  2021-10-27       AB
7         2  2021-10-27       CD
8         2  2021-10-27       CD
9         3  2021-11-10       AB
10        3  2021-11-10       AB
11        3  2021-11-10     <NA>
12        3  2021-11-11     <NA>
13        4  2021-11-24       AB
14        4  2021-11-24       AB
15        4  2021-11-24       CD
16        4  2021-11-24       CD
17        5  2021-12-01       AB
18        5  2021-12-01       AB
19        5  2021-12-01     <NA>
20        5  2021-12-01     <NA>
21        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
22        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
23        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
24        6  2021-12-05     <NA>
25        7  2021-12-15       CB
26        7  2021-12-15     <NA>
27        7  2021-12-16     <NA>
28        7  2021-12-16     <NA>

Data = structure(list(AnimalID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
                                   3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7), DateSampled = structure(c(18913, 
                                                                                                                 18913, 18913, 18913, 18927, 18927, 18927, 18927, 18941, 18941, 
                                                                                                                 18941, 18942, 18955, 18955, 18955, 18955, 18962, 18962, 18962, 
                                                                                                                 18962, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18976, 18976, 18977, 18977
                                   ), class = "Date"), Initials = c("AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", 
                                                                    "CD", "CD", "AB", "AB", NA, NA, "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "AB", 
                                                                    "AB", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "CB", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                  -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! I will update this question now. There are other NAs in the dataset that I would like to leave in the Initials column, that are independent and do not have another initial for the same date. Implementing this solution on my dataframe would delete all of the NAs in my initials column. But I would like to only delete the NAs that for the same date, have another set of initials. Thank you! Please let me know if that doesn't make sense!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your output, I updated the answer to follow your expected result. Is this what you are looking for ? I also extended the data to include another NA group, see the 'Data' section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your update! It is very helpful. Unfortunately not all of my data has NAs that always occur with 4 for one date, but I was hoping for a way to filter through and only delete rows for instances of 4 dates, 2 with initials, 2 with NA. For example, if for the same date (that has 4 rows of the same date), there is 2 rows with NA and 2 rows with a set of initials, to keep just the initials. Please let me know if there is any other way I can clarify!

Comment: I included "Update 2" in the answer. This time all the NA that don't have initial at the same date and animal ID will be kept, and the NA with initial for the same date are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would be better if you could provide an expected output.

The logic of filtering is a bit hard to understand.

From what I can gather, if you just want to remove all NA data in the Initials column and remove duplicated rows

```
Data <- Data[!is.na(Data$Initials),]
Data <- Data[!duplicated(Data),]
```

This is what I guess that you want to achieve using `tidyverse`:

- `distinct` will output only distinct row from the data
- `filter` will remove any row with NA in the Initials field

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(!is.na(Initials))
# EweID DateSampled Initials
# 1     1  2021-10-13       AB
# 2     2  2021-10-27       AB
# 3     2  2021-10-27       CD
# 4     3  2021-11-10       AB
# 5     4  2021-11-24       AB
# 6     4  2021-11-24       CD
# 7     5  2021-12-01       AB
```

If you want to still include the NA row where the EweID do not have any other Initials beside NA. Just add another step to find the EweID-DateSampled that only have NA in their Initials column

```
Data %>% distinct() %>%
  group_by(EweID, DateSampled) %>%
  summarise("var"=paste(Initials, collapse='-'))
# EweID DateSampled   var
# 1     1  2021-10-13 AB-NA
# 2     2  2021-10-27 AB-CD
# 3     3  2021-11-10 AB-NA
# 4     4  2021-11-24 AB-CD
# 5     5  2021-12-01 AB-NA
# 6     6  2021-12-02    NA
```

filter the NA row and `rbind` it to the above output

```
Data %>% distinct() %>%
  group_by(EweID, DateSampled) %>%
  summarise("var"=paste(Initials, collapse='-')) %>%
  filter(var=="NA")
# EweID DateSampled var
# 1     6  2021-12-02  NA
```